# Creating new directory not possible with String concat

Tags: java, mkdir

I am trying to create a new directory using Java but I realized that the mkdir() don't work with strings that are made up of concat() method or using the '+' operand.

For example:

```
String keyword = "golden+retriever";
String folderName = removeChar(keyword);
String strDirectory = "C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/"+folderName;
File newFolder = new File(strDirectory);

newFolder.mkdir();
```

The above code does not create the folder but it will work correctly if I were to use the directory without the '+' operand like this:

```
String strDirectory = "C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/goldenretriever";
File newFolder = new File(strDirectory);

newFolder.mkdir();
```

Why is it so? Is there any ways to successfully create a directory using the '+' operand or the concat() method?

**Update:**
The '+' in the String is not a typo. The removeChar() method simply removes the '+' in order to create a folder without special characters.

Below is the code for removeChar():

```
public static String removeChar(String s)
{
    StringBuffer buff = new StringBuffer(s.length());
    buff.setLength(s.length());
    int current = 0;

    for (int i=0; i<s.length(); i++)
    {
        char cur = s.charAt(i);
        if(cur != '+')
        {
            buff.setCharAt(current++, cur);
        }
    }

    return buff.toString();
}
```

Comment: You are not using `+` operand, the character is part of the String.  Maybe what you want to do is `String keyword = "golden" + "retriever";`. Or it's a typo in the question? What does `removeChar`?

Comment: Have you checked which is the value of `folderName` and if it is the one that should be?

Comment: what does `removeChar()` do?

Comment: The + in the string is not a typo. Because I am getting the String from Google Image URL. The removeChar() method basically removes the + sign from the String so I will be able to create a folder without any special characters.

Comment: @jl90 Can you show us the code of the `removeChar` method ?

Comment: @jl90, I believe the error is not because of `+`. Please show us your `removeChar()` method.

Comment: I have updated the post to show the removeChar() method.

Comment: Wow... Whole method to remove `+` sign.

Comment: @jl90 You could replace your `removeChar()` call with `String folderName = keyword.replace("+", "");`, but other than that, your code should work.

Comment: Do you have a permission to create folder there?

Comment: @AleksandrM thanks! I changed my code using the replace method after reading your comment and it worked.

Comment: @FlorentBayle Was editing my codes after reading the Aleksandr M's comment and read yours after I solve it. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Although you solved it using a more efficient mechanism, I have posted an answer which explains why your original code didn't work and the simple fix for your removeChar code

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that your path is proper otherwise windows allowed + as name of folder. 
see for example if I have URL like : C:/TestWS/Test/TestingDir/ then your keyword

```
String keyword = "golden+retriever";
```

Java doesn't create all directories automatically so please make sure that this path already exist before creating final keyword dir :  C:/TestWS/Test/TestingDir/

If TestingDir is not exist and trying to create "golden+retriever"; then java will not be going to create any directory.

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with your code is that the `removeChar` returns excess whitespace after the keyword. What you can do is trim it first before creating the file.

Try:

```
File newFolder = new File(strDirectory.trim());
```

And also I recommend you check if the folder exists first before creating it

```
if(!newFolder.exists()) {            
    newFolder.mkdir();
}
```

Comment: Although you are correct, `trim()` only fixes the problem after the fact. IMHO it is better to **fix** `removeChar()` so that it doesn't return extraneous trailing characters.

Answer (score 0):

Although the original poster has gone with another more efficient solution to solve the problem, I'd like to point out why their original code was failing.

They created a new `StringBuffer` and made a copy of `s` at the top. They set the initial length to be equal to the length of the original string `s`. If they removed any number of pluses the new string is actually smaller than the original. In order to make sure the StringBuffer is of the correct length with no unused trailing characters you would have to set the length accordingly when finished.

To fix the original code would require changing:

```
return buff.toString();
```

To:

```
buff.setLength(current);
return buff.toString();
```

One could have reworked the code so the new StringBuffer `buff` started out blank and new characters are simply appended as needed. That could have been done with something like:

```
public static String removeChar(String s)
{
    StringBuffer buff = new StringBuffer();

    for (int i=0; i<s.length(); i++)
    {
        char cur = s.charAt(i);
        if(cur != '+')
            buff.append(cur);
    }
    return buff.toString();
}
```